# Why is my function modifying a global variable outside its scope?

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python through MIT's OpenCourseWare, and I am having some trouble with an odd behavior of one of my functions for a problem set. It appears that my function is writing a global variable though I did not direct the function to do so which I believe is normally done with the `global` designation.

The program is a Scrabble-like game where the user is given a set of letters, and then attempts to write words to score points. Each time a word is spelled, the letters are removed from the user's hand and points are awarded if it is an actual word pre-specified in an external word list. The user is provided a single wildcard `*` which can be used to represent any vowel and allow the user to generate a word. For example, `s*ck` would be a valid word input since it could spell "sack", "sick", "sock", and so forth.

The culprit function that appears to be unexpectedly writing a global variable without me specifying to do so, is my function called `is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list)`.

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
"""
Returns True if word is in the word_list and is entirely
composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.
Does not mutate hand or word_list.

word: string
hand: dictionary (string -> int)
word_list: list of lowercase strings
returns: boolean
"""
word=word.lower()
word_converted_to_list=list(word)
vowels=['a','e','i','o','u',False]
'''Replace wildcard with letter and test for word in word_list'''
for count,letter in enumerate(word_converted_to_list): #Iterate over word_converted_to_list and save position number to 'count'
    def is_valid_word_wildcardtest(word_converted_to_list,hand): #If a wildcard is present, iterate through different vowels to see if word is present in wordlist
        for x in vowels: #If we get to the end of the list of vowels and nothing works, return a list with two False values; two values so it allows the 'if word_converted_to_list[count] == '*':' statement (outside this function) to work
            if not x:
                return [False,False]
            word_converted_to_list[count]=x
            word_test=''.join(word_converted_to_list)
            if word_test in word_list: #If we successfully find a word, then that word is returned, and the wildcard is replaced with the appropriate vowel
                word=word_test
                hand.pop('*')
                hand[x]=1
                return [word,hand]
    if word_converted_to_list[count] == '*': #Only run this function if a wildcard is present
        word=is_valid_word_wildcardtest(word_converted_to_list,hand)
        hand=word[1]
        word=word[0]
        if not word:
            return False
print(hand)
'''Check for appropriate letters in hand for word'''
if word in word_list: #Test if word is in word_list
    hand_items=list(hand.items()) #Generates a non-ordered tuple list of all kays with assigned values
    hand_list=[] #Blank list to add individual letters from hand dictionary
    for count,y in enumerate(hand_items): #Iteratively convert hand into a list with the appropriate number of letters
        for i in range(hand_items[count][1]):
            hand_list.append(y[0])
    for count in word_converted_to_list:
        try:
            hand[count] #Before checking for the appropriate number of letters, this function checks if the letter is even present in the hand
        except KeyError:
            return False
        try:
            hand_list.remove(count) #Next, the letters are iteratively removed, and if there are an insufficient number of letters, a ValueError will be returned
        except ValueError:
            return False #Function exits with a False bool
    return True #If the word exists in word_list and there are sufficient letters, return a True bool
return False #If the word is not present in word_list, return False bool
```

When I sequentially enter the following inputs, here are the results:

```
In [1]: hand={'e':1,'f':1,'*':1,'x':1}
In [2]: word_list=['fax','fix','fox']
In [3]: word='f*x'
In [4]: print(hand)
{'e':1,'f':1,'*':1,'x':1}
In [5]: is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list)
Out [5]: True
In [6]: print(hand)
{'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'x': 1, 'a': 1}
```

As you can see here, `'*'` is replaced by `'a'` which I do not want to happen. I can force my function to replace `'a'` back to `'*'` at the end, but I wanted to understand why my function was modifying a global variable. I tell the nested function to return `hand`, but I do not specify the parent function to return `hand`, so it should not be returned to the global scope.

Thanks for your help! Please let me know if I put too little (or too much!) code for me to get my question across.

Comment: You aren't modifying a *global variable*. Rather, your function mutates the object which you pass in, which is still being referenced by the global variable. Please read  https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html Note, your docstring (from what I assume is an assignment) warns you not to do this: "Does not mutate hand or word_list." But your function, in fact, *does* mutate hand.

Comment: Examples of where you mutate that object, `hand.pop('*')` and `hand[x]=1`. Note, again, *you don't modify the global variable*. `hand` is a local variable inside your function(s). You could call it `banana` and it wouldn't matter, the name doesn't matter. That doesn't mean it won't mutate the same object being referenced by the global variable, because they *are referencing the same object*. A quick fix is to *copy* the objects you are going to mutate first, maybe just at the top `hand = hand.copy()`

Comment: *Names* have scopes, and names in different scopes can refer to the same object. Objects all live in the same "global" memory space.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. If my variable `hand` exists outside the this function, and not embedded in another function, does that not make it a part of the global scope? I'm just trying to get the semantics right. I'll read the document that was posted as well, but I wanted to clarify the definition of a global versus local variable first.

Comment: @anonykit there are *three* different `hand` variables, one in the global scope, one in the local scope of `def is_valid_word` and one in the local scope of `def valid_word_wildcardtest` They are *three different variables* in three different scopes, although they have the same name in their respective scopes.  But *that isn't the issue here*. The issue is *they happen to be referring to the same object*. Again, you really should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I read the document you linked and things make much more sense now. I didn't realize that I was merely assigning new names to objects rather than generating new objects. I fixed my program to make copies of the object within the function to stop my original object from being modified. Thank you!